# How would I grep using STDIN as the query pattern, and a file as the subject?

Tags: linux, unix, grep, pattern-matching, match

Without trivially saving stdin to a file, can I take the resulting output of stdin, and USE THAT as the pattern to search against a listing in a file?

Try this example:
I have a long list.txt of lines containing filenames that I want to know if I currently have in my directory. It's the backwards equivalent of:

```
ls | grep -F -f  list.txt
```

My attempt goes as follows:

```
 grep -F -f  $( ls -1 ) list.txt
```

But that doesn't work. 
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the keyword `-` or `/dev/stdin` as the filename in your original form.

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know that you could use dash or /dev/stdin as a representation of stdin. Does this apply to other bash utilities as well? Or is it specific to grep?

Comment: Various programs recognize the `-` syntax, though not necessarily all. `/dev/stdin` should have an even better coverage, but it is longer to type.